# ¿Cómo quitar los ' ' entre los elementos de una lista?

Tags: python

como convierto las siguientes listas

como paso este tipo de lista:

```
['(3,1)', '(1,3)', '(2,3)', '(1,1)', '(1,2)']
```

a este tipo:

```
[(3,1), (1,3), (2,3), (1,1), (1,2)]
```

se puede?

Comment: Tu pregunta es si se puede, si pues, se puede... Como, pues has intentado algo??

Comment: Bienvenido @NicolasEscandon a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: modo altamente inseguro: usar `eval()` modo seguro: usar la librería `ast` y la función `literal_eval()`

Comment: ¿Y al final qué quieres?¿una _string_ para imprimir en pantalla o una lista de tuplas?

Answer (score 3):

Una solución trabajosa:

```
lista = ['(3,1)', '(1,3)', '(2,3)', '(1,1)', '(1,2)']
final = []
for sublista in lista:
    a, b = sublista[1:-1].split(",")
    final.append((int(a), int(b)))

print(final)
```

En cada iteración del `for` se extrae un elemento, por ejemplo, `sublista = '(3,1)'`. Con rebanado de lista descartamos los paréntesis, obteniendo `'3,1'`, que separamos en sus partes usando `split`.

Los valores obtenidos (`a` y `b`) son cadenas, por las que debo convertirlas en enteros, poner dentro de una tupla y agregarla a la lista final.

Resultado:

```
[(3, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 1), (1, 2)]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

La funcion integrada eval() sirve para extraer cualquier literal que se encuentre en una cadena y convertirlo a un valor de python, puede ser una lista literal como esta "[0, 2, 4, 6]", una tupla "(1, 3, 5)" o un diccionario como este "{ "a": 10, "b": 20}".

```
#python

lista_1 = ['(3,1)', '(1,3)', '(2,3)', '(1,1)', '(1,2)']

lista_2 = []

for elemento in lista_1:
    lista_2.append(eval(elemento))
    
print(lista_2)
```

Para resolver el problema planteado crearemos una lista vacía y usamos un bucle for para recorrer toda la lista dada, usamos la funcion eval() para covertir las cadenas a tuplas de python, el metodo .append() sirve para añadir un elemento a una lista cualquiera.

Comment: Recomiendo entregar una descripcion de lo que hiciste.